# What is a better way to write this SQL Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am updating a Trades Transactions Log using a SQL Stored Procedure, and I am updating Current Order Table at the same time with the same sproc.

Because I had a serious problem where the Log table did not update and the Current Order table did... I added a (3rd) routine to the bottom which checks to see if the Log Table was updated referencing an ID (ClientID), then entering an error if not present to error table.

I am asking... how badly written is this sproc ??  Help or advice appreciated.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sprocVT4_addTradeLong
@seqno varchar(35) = NULL,
@exctyp varchar(35) = NULL,
@ordstat varchar(35) = NULL,
@clid varchar(35) = NULL,
@exid varchar(35) = NULL,
@type varchar(35) = NULL,
@side varchar(35) = NULL,
@exch varchar(35) = NULL,
@sym varchar(35) = NULL,
@lstqty varchar(35) = NULL,
@lstpri varchar(35) = NULL,
@text varchar(35) = NULL,
@cumqty varchar(35) = NULL,
@lftqty varchar(35) = NULL,
@now varchar(35) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
-- NO EXISTS ------------
Declare @RC int

SELECT [Symbol] FROM TradesLongForex T WHERE T.ExecId = @exid

SELECT @RC = @@ROWCOUNT
IF @RC <= 0

INSERT INTO TradesLongForex ([SeqNo], [ExecType], [Status], [ClientId], [ExecId], [Type], [Side], [Exchange], [Symbol], [LastQty], [LastPrice], [Text], [CummQty], [LeftQty], [Date])

VALUES (@seqno, @exctyp, @ordstat, @clid, @exid, @type, @side, @exch, @sym, @lstqty, @lstpri, @text, @cumqty, @lftqty, @now)

UPDATE OrdersIdHoldForex SET [OrdExcType] = @exctyp, [OrdStatus] = @ordstat, [OrdType] = @type, [OrdSide] = @side, [OrdPrice] = @lstpri, [OrdQty] = @cumqty, [OrdRemain] = @lftqty

WHERE [Ticker] = @sym

DECLARE @RC2 int

SELECT @RC2 = @@ROWCOUNT

SELECT [ClientId] FROM TradesLongForex WHERE [ClientId] = @clid
if @RC2 <=0

INSERT INTO ERRLOG ([Date], [Message])

VALUES (GETDATE(), 'ERROR INSERTING TRADESLONGFOREX CLID = ' + CONVERT(varchar(10),@CLID))

END
```

Comment: Without further background decribing what you are trying to do it's hard to give a suggestion as to how this could be improved. From just looking at what you posted though it seems straight-forward enough to leave as-is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phil makes a good point about transactions.  This concept is called "Atomicity" and basically means each transaction/process is atomic and self contained.

The general syntax for transactions in SQL server would be something like:

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION
...

your code here

...

COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 1 ROLLBACK

... error reporting code ...

END CATCH
```

The gist of this is, use `TRY/CATCH` blocks to trap the errors, and only commit the transaction if you get through the whole `TRY` block without issues.  Any errors send you to the `CATCH` block, which rolls back the open transaction.

[Here's a primer on error handling.](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3651861/Error-handling-in-SQL-Server-2005.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are asking, but it seems that you need to read up a bit on database transactions.  Essentially you can wrap the set of queries in a transaction, and it will ensure that either all of the operations are completed, or none of them are.  So if an error occurs, the entire operation will be rolled back.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction

Comment: at a higher level, perhaps but this sproc is recording completed events so I need to know about it no matter what.